# Overwriting vector data

Tags: c++, vector

I've got a function that uses a 2d string type vector. The function should read data from a file, store it into vector A and push back A into B. Then, the loop gets new values for A, which should overwrite the previous ones. How am I supposed to do this? Is there any way to "reset" the vector, so that `vector.push_back()` inserts data from the beggining, instead of attaching it to the end?

Comment: What hast thou tried?

Comment: Well you can clear a vector if you want to discard its current contents.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've tried using `vector.reserve()` and then editting vector[0], vector[1] etc, but it's not really comfortable and doesn't even work.

Comment: @photons3432: [Let's look at some documentation.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) Have you tried using `vector.clear()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a single dimension vector of `std::string`s and just use [`std::vector::clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) to remove the old content before `std::vector::insert`ing the next.

Notice that `clear` just removes all the elements, but leaves the capacity unchanged.

If you really have to keep the 2 dimention vector, then just apply what I said to `vector[0]` or any generic `vector[i]` vector you may need to work on.

Comment: Wierd, I've tried using that earlier and it didn't seem to work, but now it does... Anyway, many thanks